# php string to image imagecreatefromstring fault

Tags: php, image, binary

I want to convert this text to jpeg using php.
I can convert wit using [this site](http://www.motobit.com/util/base64-decoder-encoder.asp) but when I try to convert with imagecreatefromstring library I get Data is not in a recognized format error.

```
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcg SlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0IHF1YWxpdHkK/9sAQwAIBgYHBgUIBwcHCQkICgwUDQwLCwwZEhMP FB0aHx4dGhwcICQuJyAiLCMcHCg3KSwwMTQ0NB8nOT04MjwuMzQy/9sAQwEJCQkMCwwYDQ0YMiEc ITIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIy/8AAEQgA ZAGQAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMC BAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYn KCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeY mZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5 +v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwAB AgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpD REVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ip qrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMR AD8A6qiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAo oooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACii igAooooAKKKKACiitzQNFt9VjmeeSRfLYABCBnP1FAGHRXcjwppg6iY/V6H8J6aw485PcP8A4igD hqK6PUPCc0EbSWcpmA5MZGGx7etc4Rg4PWgAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKK KACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAoooo AK67wb/x73X++v8AI1yNdd4N/wCPe6/31/kaAKni2aVNTiRJXVfJB2hiBnc1Ycd7dQsGjuZUPs5r oPFVndXGpxPBbTSqIQCUQsM7m9KyIdD1OdgFs5Fz3cbf50Add4e1KTUrBjOcyxttZgMbh2Nct4ig SDW5wgwGw+Pcjn9a6nTrWHw/pTG5mUEnc7ds+g9a4vUbxr+/muSMbzwPQDgfpQBVorc8N2NndyXD 3ihkiVSNzYAznrW8b7w9aHaDagj/AJ5xbv1AoA4Wiu9hvNC1BxEgt3c8BXiwT9MisnxDoENrAby0 UqqkeZH1Az3FAHMUUV31lpdlLo9uxtIDI9up3FBkkr1zQBwNFdnBpOlaLAsuovHJKe7jI/Be9Xba 40bUyYolt5Dj7jR4P4AigDz+iuh8R6JHYhbq1BELNtZOu0+3tXPUAFFehXmi2c1nLHBa28crLhX2 AYPrVJLLRdCjQXbRvMRndIu4n6LzgUAcVRXoUB0fVkZYkt5cdRsww/TNcr4g0ddMuFeHJglztB52 n0oAx6KdHG8sixopZ2OFA6k12mn+HLKxt/OvQksgGWL/AHF/D/GgDiaK7n+19AVvKzDjpxAdv8qT UfD9lqFt51ksccpGUaP7j/0/GgDh6KV0aN2RwVZTgg9jXW+FrG1udMkee2ilYTEAugJxtWgDkaK6 mbw4b3XLnYot7NCoG1cZ+UZCj+taS6ZoNgNkotw3czSAk/gTQBwlFXdX8j+1Z/s3l+TkbfLxt6Dp iqVABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAV13g3/AI97r/fX+Rrk a67wb/x73X++v8jQBpanr1tpdysE0crMyB8oBjGSO59qrxeLNNc4YTx+7ICP0JrH8X/8haL/AK4D /wBCaufoA7m80ey1uL7TBdPuP3WDll+mD0/SuNvLSaxuXt51w6+nQj1HtW34PmddQmhBPltFuI9w Rz+tWfGUS4tZsfP8yk+o4P8AjQBymeMdqv22jajdqGitXKnozYUH862PC2lRTK19Ooba22NT0z3N XtZ8SDT7g21vEskq/eZj8q+3HWgDFj8M6qjq6oispyD5g4NdfqqCTSbxT/zxY/iBmuQ/4SnU2bgx c9AErsdR/wCQXd/9cX/9BNAHmdelaX/yCbL/AK4J/wCgivNa9K0v/kE2X/XBP/QRQB5/qF7JqF7J PIxOT8o/ur2FJp8zQajbSqcFZF/LPNVqkg/4+Iv98fzoA77xCgfQroHsAR+BFee16Lrn/IEu/wDr nXnVAHqFzN9ntZp8Z8tGfHrgZrzOeeW5neaZy0jnJJr0bVP+QTe/9cH/APQTXmtAGp4emaHXLbB4 clCPUEV0fi1A2jqx6rKCPyNcvov/ACGrT/rqK6vxV/yBG/66LQBgeFbdZ9YDsMiJC4+vA/rWx4se 4a1gt4UkZXYs+wE9MYB/P9Kz/BzD+0J17mLP6iug1XWY9JMXmRO4kzgrjjGP8aAOD+x3X/PtN/3w a67wmZ1sZoZo3UI+V3Ajr/8Aq/Wo/wDhMbX/AJ9ZvzFH/CY2v/PrN+YoAxfEsIh1ubbwHAf8xz+t b3hD/kEy/wDXc/8AoK1zes6imp332iNGRdgXDdeK6Twh/wAgmX/ruf8A0FaAI/FGrS2uyzt3KM67 nYdQOwFccTk5PWtnxSf+J5J/uL/KsagAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACi iigAooooAKKKKACuu8G/8e91/vr/ACNcjWvo2uHSVlX7P5okIP38Yx+FAGl4o0+8utRjlgt5JEEI UlRnnJ/xrGj0PU5WwtnIP94bf510C+Mbf+K0lH0YGhvGNuB8tpKT7sBQBc0DRTpcbyTMrTyAA7ei j0rE8WXyXF7HbRnIgB3Ef3j2/DFR3viq8uUKQqtuh6lTlvzrCJycnrQB3PhSZX0fywfmjchh9eax de0a8GpyzwwSTRyncCi5IPcHFZmnalcaZcebARg8MjdGFdGnjGAoN9pIG7gMCKAKei+HLhrpLi9j 8qKM7gjdWI6cdhXUagQdKuiDkGB8Ef7prkNT8S3N/EYYkEETcMAcsw9M1PJ4r8ywe1+xY3RGPd5v tjOMUAc5XpWl/wDIJsv+uCf+givNa6W18W/ZrSGD7Du8qNU3ebjOBjPSgDmqkg/4+Iv98fzqOnRt skV8Z2kHFAHoeuf8gS7/AOudedV0d94q+22U1t9i2eYuN3m5x+GK5ygD0rVP+QTe/wDXB/8A0E15 rXS3Xi37TaTQfYdvmxsm7zc4yMZ6VzVAF/Rf+Q1af9dRXV+Kv+QI3/XRa4yyufsd7DcbN/lsG25x mtbVfEf9p2Rtvsnl5YNu8zPT2xQBS0W+Gn6pFM/+rPyv9D3/AK12WtaaNWsAsbL5infG2eD7fQ15 7WtpviG705BFxNCOiP2+hoAqTaZfQOVktJgfZCR+Yp9vo2o3LAR2koB/icbR+ZroV8ZQEfPaSA+z A1HN4yGMQ2Zz6u/9AKAOVZSjsp6g4Ndp4Q/5BMv/AF3P/oK1xjtvdmPViTWzo/iD+ybR4Psvm7pC +7zNvYDHQ+lADfFH/Ick/wBxf5VjVd1S/wD7SvmufK8vcANu7PT3xVKgAooooAKKKKACiiigAooo oAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiig AooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAC iiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKK KKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/9k= ­
```

Answer (score 5):

This string is encoded result of a picture. in order to see the picture, prepend `data:image/jpeg;base64` to the encoded string

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $data; ?>" />
```

`$data` is the variable holds encoded data. Then you will be able to see the picture

```
<?php 

$str = "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD//gA+Q1JFQVRPUjogZ2QtanBlZyB2MS4wICh1c2luZyBJSkcg SlBFRyB2NjIpLCBkZWZhdWx0IHF1YWxpdHkK/9sAQwAIBgYHBgUIBwcHCQkICgwUDQwLCwwZEhMP FB0aHx4dGhwcICQuJyAiLCMcHCg3KSwwMTQ0NB8nOT04MjwuMzQy/9sAQwEJCQkMCwwYDQ0YMiEc ITIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIy/8AAEQgA ZAGQAwEiAAIRAQMRAf/EAB8AAAEFAQEBAQEBAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALUQAAIBAwMC BAMFBQQEAAABfQECAwAEEQUSITFBBhNRYQcicRQygZGhCCNCscEVUtHwJDNicoIJChYXGBkaJSYn KCkqNDU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6g4SFhoeIiYqSk5SVlpeY mZqio6Slpqeoqaqys7S1tre4ubrCw8TFxsfIycrS09TV1tfY2drh4uPk5ebn6Onq8fLz9PX29/j5 +v/EAB8BAAMBAQEBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAABAgMEBQYHCAkKC//EALURAAIBAgQEAwQHBQQEAAECdwAB AgMRBAUhMQYSQVEHYXETIjKBCBRCkaGxwQkjM1LwFWJy0QoWJDThJfEXGBkaJicoKSo1Njc4OTpD REVGR0hJSlNUVVZXWFlaY2RlZmdoaWpzdHV2d3h5eoKDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ip qrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uLj5OXm5+jp6vLz9PX29/j5+v/aAAwDAQACEQMR AD8A6qiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAo oooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACii igAooooAKKKKACiitzQNFt9VjmeeSRfLYABCBnP1FAGHRXcjwppg6iY/V6H8J6aw485PcP8A4igD hqK6PUPCc0EbSWcpmA5MZGGx7etc4Rg4PWgAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKK KACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAoooo AK67wb/x73X++v8AI1yNdd4N/wCPe6/31/kaAKni2aVNTiRJXVfJB2hiBnc1Ycd7dQsGjuZUPs5r oPFVndXGpxPBbTSqIQCUQsM7m9KyIdD1OdgFs5Fz3cbf50Add4e1KTUrBjOcyxttZgMbh2Nct4ig SDW5wgwGw+Pcjn9a6nTrWHw/pTG5mUEnc7ds+g9a4vUbxr+/muSMbzwPQDgfpQBVorc8N2NndyXD 3ihkiVSNzYAznrW8b7w9aHaDagj/AJ5xbv1AoA4Wiu9hvNC1BxEgt3c8BXiwT9MisnxDoENrAby0 UqqkeZH1Az3FAHMUUV31lpdlLo9uxtIDI9up3FBkkr1zQBwNFdnBpOlaLAsuovHJKe7jI/Be9Xba 40bUyYolt5Dj7jR4P4AigDz+iuh8R6JHYhbq1BELNtZOu0+3tXPUAFFehXmi2c1nLHBa28crLhX2 AYPrVJLLRdCjQXbRvMRndIu4n6LzgUAcVRXoUB0fVkZYkt5cdRsww/TNcr4g0ddMuFeHJglztB52 n0oAx6KdHG8sixopZ2OFA6k12mn+HLKxt/OvQksgGWL/AHF/D/GgDiaK7n+19AVvKzDjpxAdv8qT UfD9lqFt51ksccpGUaP7j/0/GgDh6KV0aN2RwVZTgg9jXW+FrG1udMkee2ilYTEAugJxtWgDkaK6 mbw4b3XLnYot7NCoG1cZ+UZCj+taS6ZoNgNkotw3czSAk/gTQBwlFXdX8j+1Z/s3l+TkbfLxt6Dp iqVABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAV13g3/AI97r/fX+Rrk a67wb/x73X++v8jQBpanr1tpdysE0crMyB8oBjGSO59qrxeLNNc4YTx+7ICP0JrH8X/8haL/AK4D /wBCaufoA7m80ey1uL7TBdPuP3WDll+mD0/SuNvLSaxuXt51w6+nQj1HtW34PmddQmhBPltFuI9w Rz+tWfGUS4tZsfP8yk+o4P8AjQBymeMdqv22jajdqGitXKnozYUH862PC2lRTK19Ooba22NT0z3N XtZ8SDT7g21vEskq/eZj8q+3HWgDFj8M6qjq6oispyD5g4NdfqqCTSbxT/zxY/iBmuQ/4SnU2bgx c9AErsdR/wCQXd/9cX/9BNAHmdelaX/yCbL/AK4J/wCgivNa9K0v/kE2X/XBP/QRQB5/qF7JqF7J PIxOT8o/ur2FJp8zQajbSqcFZF/LPNVqkg/4+Iv98fzoA77xCgfQroHsAR+BFee16Lrn/IEu/wDr nXnVAHqFzN9ntZp8Z8tGfHrgZrzOeeW5neaZy0jnJJr0bVP+QTe/9cH/APQTXmtAGp4emaHXLbB4 clCPUEV0fi1A2jqx6rKCPyNcvov/ACGrT/rqK6vxV/yBG/66LQBgeFbdZ9YDsMiJC4+vA/rWx4se 4a1gt4UkZXYs+wE9MYB/P9Kz/BzD+0J17mLP6iug1XWY9JMXmRO4kzgrjjGP8aAOD+x3X/PtN/3w a67wmZ1sZoZo3UI+V3Ajr/8Aq/Wo/wDhMbX/AJ9ZvzFH/CY2v/PrN+YoAxfEsIh1ubbwHAf8xz+t b3hD/kEy/wDXc/8AoK1zes6imp332iNGRdgXDdeK6Twh/wAgmX/ruf8A0FaAI/FGrS2uyzt3KM67 nYdQOwFccTk5PWtnxSf+J5J/uL/KsagAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACi iigAooooAKKKKACuu8G/8e91/vr/ACNcjWvo2uHSVlX7P5okIP38Yx+FAGl4o0+8utRjlgt5JEEI UlRnnJ/xrGj0PU5WwtnIP94bf510C+Mbf+K0lH0YGhvGNuB8tpKT7sBQBc0DRTpcbyTMrTyAA7ei j0rE8WXyXF7HbRnIgB3Ef3j2/DFR3viq8uUKQqtuh6lTlvzrCJycnrQB3PhSZX0fywfmjchh9eax de0a8GpyzwwSTRyncCi5IPcHFZmnalcaZcebARg8MjdGFdGnjGAoN9pIG7gMCKAKei+HLhrpLi9j 8qKM7gjdWI6cdhXUagQdKuiDkGB8Ef7prkNT8S3N/EYYkEETcMAcsw9M1PJ4r8ywe1+xY3RGPd5v tjOMUAc5XpWl/wDIJsv+uCf+givNa6W18W/ZrSGD7Du8qNU3ebjOBjPSgDmqkg/4+Iv98fzqOnRt skV8Z2kHFAHoeuf8gS7/AOudedV0d94q+22U1t9i2eYuN3m5x+GK5ygD0rVP+QTe/wDXB/8A0E15 rXS3Xi37TaTQfYdvmxsm7zc4yMZ6VzVAF/Rf+Q1af9dRXV+Kv+QI3/XRa4yyufsd7DcbN/lsG25x mtbVfEf9p2Rtvsnl5YNu8zPT2xQBS0W+Gn6pFM/+rPyv9D3/AK12WtaaNWsAsbL5infG2eD7fQ15 7WtpviG705BFxNCOiP2+hoAqTaZfQOVktJgfZCR+Yp9vo2o3LAR2koB/icbR+ZroV8ZQEfPaSA+z A1HN4yGMQ2Zz6u/9AKAOVZSjsp6g4Ndp4Q/5BMv/AF3P/oK1xjtvdmPViTWzo/iD+ybR4Psvm7pC +7zNvYDHQ+lADfFH/Ick/wBxf5VjVd1S/wD7SvmufK8vcANu7PT3xVKgAooooAKKKKACiiigAooo oAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiig AooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAC iiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKK KKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAP/9k=";
?>


<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo $str; ?>" />
```

Comment: Even if the op wanted to merely display the image, the string is already base64 encoded.

Comment: @AmalMurali I use it in this way and works fine. No problem. Do I know something wrong? Please tell me.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ: [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4jH6kO) will work, but [this](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gK6f3G) won't.

Comment: @AmalMurali are the things differend for BLOB? Becuase I have just tried you warned me, while my way is working, yours is not. I am getting image from DB as BLOB which it is encoded base64.

Comment: @ÖzkanÖZLÜ: The OP already has the base64 decoded string and I don't really understand why you'd want to re-encode it *once again*. And where does `BLOB`s from from? It doesn't matter how *you* are getting the image. The OP asks `convert this text to jpeg using php`, not `how to display the base64 encoded image fetched from db`.

Comment: @AmalMurali I understand what you are saying. But I ask you if the things are different for BLOB images. Because when I remove base64_encode() function, I see only characters in my own page. Even if BLOB is encoded.

Comment: Guys, When I try to convert str='...'  to image it works. for example if I copy all text above str='/9j/4AAQS........' it works. But if I want to print something like echo $data it doesn`t work. When I copy echo $data to my new str=" " manually it works but I don't use $data directly.

Comment: @user1472060: It will work. See [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/4jH6kO) I posted earlier.

Comment: I get $str from database and when I try to use it directly it prints string not jpeg. When I copy content of string like you $str = '/9j/4AAQSkZ.......' it works. How can I solve this.

Answer (score 2):

The string seems to be base64 encoded, use

```
$str = '...';
$image = imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($str));
```