# Convert php string to image

Tags: php, string, image, gd

I want to convert a php string to an image.
I use this code

```
header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = '.the_title().';

$font  = 5;
$width  = imagefontwidth($font) * strlen($string);
$height = imagefontheight($font);

$image = imagecreatetruecolor ($width,$height);
$white = imagecolorallocate ($image,255,255,255);
$black = imagecolorallocate ($image,0,0,0);
imagefill($image,0,0,$white);

imagestring ($image,$font,0,0,$string,$black);

imagepng ($image);
imagedestroy($image)
```

but its shows the_title as text instead of executing the string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php string to image imagecreatefromstring fault](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19083677/php-string-to-image-imagecreatefromstring-fault)

Comment: its not duplicated read the complete post its about a base64 string

Answer (score 5):

Use `imagecreatefromstring`

```
$string = '.the_title().';

$data = base64_decode($string);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
if ($im !== false) {
    header('Content-Type: image/png');
    imagepng($im);
    imagedestroy($im);
}
```

Comment: doesnt display anything

Comment: @ninju you just copy / paste the php sample without testing…

Comment: i didn't test it.it's just for reference

Comment: refrence for what? this isnt working with a php string..its works with a base64 encoded string but that was not my question

Answer (score 1):

Use [`imagestring`](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.imagestring.php) like:

```
<?php

$string = the_title();

$im = imagecreate(150, 20); // image size 150x20px
imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255); // background white
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0); // text color black

imagestring($im, 3, 5, 5, $string, $text_color); // append string to image

header('Content-type: image/png'); // filetype
imagepng($im, 'image.png'); // save as image.png
imagedestroy($im); // free up memory
```

Comment: Search if `gd` is present in your `phpinfo();` See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26161655/which-entry-in-phpinfo-tells-about-the-gd-library

Comment: gd is enabled your code just isnt working. im able to use "my code" above with a normal text string (returns image)

Comment: I try it with the string "test" and it's works. So with the string 'the_title()'; it's works.

Comment: maybe there is a typo anywhere. i just tried the "imagestring code" from php.net and replace the text string with $string. this works but just returns the_title() instead of executing the php string

Comment: the image creation was also working with my code thats not my problem. my problem is that the_title()  should return the title of posts. thats not happening the image which get created just has the text the_title() in it instead of the post name

Comment: If `echo the_title();` return string, replace `$string = 'the_title()';` by `$string = the_title();`

Comment: now i get the image created but still without the title just a blank image, at least i know now that the problem is the string. because im using wordpress i guess i move over to stackexchange wordpress section to get help. thanks for your help